# Crunching Gears

Tags: gears

I had a crash a while back on my road bike and I checked my bike thoroughly and it seemed pretty good. I went on a ride today and the gears were constantly crunching, shifting between gears was fine but when in a gear it crunched.
Any ideas what this may be and how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: We really need more information. Can you ask someone to lift it up or suspend it (e.g. a loop of string) so you can spin the pedals and take a close look at the drivetrain in action? It could be anything: bent rear derailleur hanger, bent/broken chainring teeth, bent/stiff chain links, slightly unseated rear wheel …

Comment: The obvious suggestion is a bent derailleur hanger.  They are supposed to bend easily to protect the derailleur.  When bent, the derailleur is no longer properly aligned.